# application terminate help

Tags: delphi, forms

in my project i have two forms ,when i clicked show form 2 button in form1 ,form2 will pop up ,i want to terminate my whole application by clicking close button on form2 ,

can anyone  please tell me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean when a TButton called Close is clicked, then in the Button.OnClick event call `Application.Terminate;`

If you mean when the form's X button is clicked, then in Form2's OnClose event, call `Application.Terminate;`

Answer (score 17):

Do not use `Application.Terminate` if you want your `OnCloseQuery` and `OnClose` handlers of the main app form to be called (for example to be able to cancel this or to ask whether to save modified files or such).

You can call

```
Application.MainForm.Close;
```

instead, from all forms (even the main form itself).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to send a wm_Close message to the application/application.mainform

```
PostMessage(Application.Handle,wm_Close,0,0);
```

or

```
PostMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle,wm_Close,0,0);
```

This places the close request in the message queue, existing messages already in the message queue will continue to process first.

Answer (score -5):

The post easiest mode is to user
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcessID, 0);
no ask, no freeze, no s*iet.

Comment: As the API help says, "The TerminateProcess function is used to unconditionally cause a process to exit. Use it only in extreme circumstances.". Application.Terminate calls the PostQuitMessage function which allows threads and other processes to exit gracefully.